# Present importXML output in reverse order

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, importxml

How to reverse the order of the output of `imporxml`? For example,  `=importxml("http://example.com","//p")` outputs

```
+---+---------------------+
| 1 | This domain is ...  |
| 2 | More information... |
+---+---------------------+
```

and I want

```
+---+---------------------+
| 1 | More information... |
| 2 | This domain is ...  |
+---+---------------------+
```

I know various ways to reverse a range already present in a sheet, for example

```
=query({A:A, arrayformula(row(A:A))}, "select Col1 where Col1 <> '' order by Col2 desc")
```

outputs nonempty cells in column A in reverse order. However, I'd like to reverse the order without the intermediate step of placing the output in the sheet. Trying `arrayformula(row(importxml(...)))` throws an error: "Argument must be a range".

Comment: Instead of row(importxml(...)) use something like row(A1:A10)

Comment: The number of results is unknown (it may change as the content changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTA and ARRAY_CONSTRAIN to set the size of the sequential number array to be used as the sort column. Example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ROW(A:A),COUNTA(IMPORTXML(range,xpath)),1))
```

The final formula should look like the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
     SORT(
       {
         IMPORTXML(url,xpath),
         ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ROW(A:A),COUNTA(IMPORTXML(url,xpath)),1))
       },
       2,
       FALSE
     ),
     1E100,
     1
   )
 )
```

Comment: 1E1000 is a lot...

Comment: @404 that is the idea :)

Comment: Actually it was too large. Just remove one `0`.